# How does SWIG wrap a map<string,string> in Python?

Tags: c++, python, stl, swig

I'm using SWIG 2.0 to create a Python wrapper for a C++ library.  One method has an argument of type "const std::map&".  SWIG happily generates a wrapper for it, but I can't figure out how to invoke the method.  If I pass, for example, {"a":"b"} for that argument, I get a "NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function" error.

I looked at the generated .cxx file in the hope it would clarify, but it didn't.  Here's the code that processes that argument:

```
res4 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj3, &argp4, SWIGTYPE_p_std__mapT_std__string_std__string_t,  0  | 0);
if (!SWIG_IsOK(res4)) {
  SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res4), "in method '" "new_Context" "', argument " "4"" of type '" "std::map< std::string,std::string > const &""'"); 
}
```

It clearly knows that argument exists, and that it's supposed to be something that gets converted to a map.  But I can't figure out what it actually wants me to pass for it.

Comment: In your swig file to you explicitly wrap the map? I think you need to create a variable of the type the populate by calling insert from within the python code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you're using a C++ template (e.g. a `std::map<string, string>`) you need to create an alias for it in your `.i` file so you can use it in python:

```
namespace std {
%template(map_string_string) map<string, string>;
}
```

Now let's say you want to wrap a function that looks like this:

```
void foo(const std::map<string, string> &arg);
```

On the python side, you need to pass a map_string_string to foo, not a python dict.  It turns out that you can easily convert a python dict to a map though by doing this:

```
map_string_string({ 'a' : 'b' })
```

so if you want to call foo, you need to do this:

```
foo(map_string_string({ 'a' : 'b' }))
```

Here's full example code that works.

```
// test.i
%module test

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_map.i"

namespace std {
    %template(map_string_string) map<string, string>;
}

void foo(const std::map<std::string, std::string> &val);

%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
void
foo(const map<string, string> &val)
{
    map<string, string>::const_iterator i = val.begin();
    map<string, string>::const_iterator end = val.end();
    while (i != end) {
        cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << endl;
        ++i;
    }
}

%}
```

And the python test code:

```
#run_test.py
import test

x = test.map_string_string({ 'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd' })
test.foo(x)
```

And my command line:

```
% swig -python -c++ test.i
% g++ -fPIC -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7  -o _test.so test_wrap.cxx
% python run_test.py
a : b
c : d
```

Comment: It appears you don't even need to use the map_string_string type in your Python code.  Once you declare the template, SWIG can automatically figure out how to convert a dict to it.