# SWIG C++ function that takes an std::map results in "NotImplementedError" in Python

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'm trying to write a simple C++ function that takes an std::map as an argument, and exposes that function to Python. I've looked at SWIG examples, and also found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041192/how-does-swig-wrap-a-mapstring-string-in-python). It works great when a C++ function *returns* an std::map, but I can't get it to properly construct one. I get an error that looks like this:

```
>>> example.take_map(example.map_string_string({'hello': 'world'}))
...
NotImplementedError: Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function 'new_map_string_string'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    std::map< std::string,std::string >(std::less< std::string > const &)
    std::map< std::string,std::string >()
    std::map< std::string,std::string >(std::map< std::string,std::string > const &)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have found a bug in the SWIG code that differentiates which overloaded function to call for Python.  This bug only appears in certain situations.  Can you try temporarily disabling the other overloads and see if your function now works?  If it does, you can write custom Python code in your SWIG .i file to work around the problem.

Comment: @bluedog Actually the reason I was getting these errors was because I was using SWIG packaged with Python 2.7, and then importing the module using Python 2.5. Once I got the versions to match up, it all worked out.